# Replace continuous 0s to 1s in an one-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy one-dimensional array of 1s and 0s. for e.g

```
a = np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])
```

I want to replace continuous 0s to 1s if the length of the continuous 0s is less than a threshold, let said 2. and the first and last continuous 0s would be excluded. So it would output a new array like this

```
out: [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
```

if threshold is 4 the output would be

```
out: [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]
```

What I do is counting each segments' length
I got this solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994973/how-to-count-continuous-numbers-in-numpy/)

```
segLengs = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate(([True], a[1:]!= a[:-1], [True] ))))

out: [1,3,7,1,1,2,3,2,2]
```

Then find the segments which is less than the threshold

```
gaps = np.where(segLengs <= threshold)[0]
gapsNeedPadding = gaps[gaps % 2 == 0]
```

And then loop though `gapsNeedPadding` array

also `itertools.groupby` could do the job but it would be a little bit slow

Is there a more efficient solution? I would prefer vectorize solution. speed is what I need. I already got a slow solution which loop though the array

**Update**

Tried the solution provide from @divakar in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893319/find-consecutive-unmasked-values), but it seems like it could not solve my problem when the threshold is larger.

`numpy_binary_closing` and `binary_closing` have different output. Also both function won't CLOSE from the boundaries + threshold

Did I make any mistake in the following code?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import binary_closing

def numpy_binary_closing(mask,threshold):

    # Define kernel
    K = np.ones(threshold)

    # Perform dilation and threshold at 1
    dil = np.convolve(mask, K, mode='same') >= 1

    # Perform erosion on the dilated mask array and threshold at given threshold
    dil_erd = np.convolve(dil, K, mode='same') >= threshold
    return dil_erd

threshold = 4
mask = np.random.rand(100) > 0.5

print(mask.astype(int))
out1 = numpy_binary_closing(mask, threshold)
out2 = binary_closing(mask, structure=np.ones(threshold))
print(out1.astype(int))
print(out2.astype(int))
print(np.allclose(out1,out2))
```

**Outout**

```
[0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1]

[0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]

[0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]

False
```

Comment: why are the last two `0`s not replaced?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis first and last continuous 0s would be excluded

Comment: Is the threshold a constant?

Comment: @DYZ No it is not, it could be from 2 to 100+

Comment: @Divakar tried your solution from the other question, but I got some strange problem.

Comment: @EricSo As suggested at the start of the dup target, `OR` the input array/mask with the binary closing output.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any better idea:

```
for _ in range(threshold - 1):
    a |= np.roll(a, 1)
```

(This code does not take care of the trailing zeros.)

Comment: if threshold is 3 it outputs 

    Out[7]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

Does not seem to be working?